# How to detect user-made changes of a NumericUpDown field in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

Having many `NumericUpDown` fields on my form I want all of them recalculated whenever a user edits one of them.

Needless to say I can't just use `ValueChanged` event because it is also triggered by programmatic change which gives us an infinite loop.

So how can I distinguish user-made adjustments from programmatic property changes?

I need a user to be able of editing the fields both ways - by clicking increment/decrement buttons and by editing the field text directly.

Comment: Why can't you do a simple "if (oldValue == newValue)" check in the ValueChanged callback(s) to break the infinite loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want a global flag you can always temporarily unwire the event right before changing the value programatically:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    numericUpDown.ValueChanged -= numericUpDown_ValueChanged;
    numericUpDown.Value = 100;
    numericUpDown.ValueChanged += numericUpDown_ValueChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some `Reflection` with a notice about the internal field `currentValue` and create your own `NumericUpDown` like this:

```
public class CustomNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown {
    static System.Reflection.FieldInfo currentValue;
    static CustomNumericUpDown() {
        currentValue = typeof(NumericUpDown).GetField("currentValue",
                             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
    public CustomNumericUpDown() {
        RaiseValueChangedOnlyByUser = true;
    }
    public bool RaiseValueChangedOnlyByUser { get; set; }
    public new decimal Value {
        get { return base.Value; }
        set
        {
            if (RaiseValueChangedOnlyByUser){
                currentValue.SetValue(this, value);
                UpdateEditText();
            }
            else base.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
//Then in your code just use the `Value` normally, it won't
//never fire the ValueChanged event unless user changes it via the UI
//You can set the RaiseValueChangedOnlyByUser to false to 
//enable firing ValueChanged when the value is changed by code (like as 
//the standard NumericUpDown does)
```

Comment: Reflection is highly time-consuming. You should use it only when no other option and here you have many alternatives. Coming up with innovative approaches is always nice, but cannot make performance unnecessarily worse.

Comment: @varocarbas do you know `DataBindings` in `winforms` and in even `wpf`? They are all based on `Reflection`. This is of course not really recommended, it's a choice. However you can see its benefit that the code later (outside the class) will be very neat. there are also many other stuff based on `reflection`, such as `dynamic`... At least in this case I don't see much decrease in performance. **I have used the solution posted in your answer for years**, that's very popular and well-known when programming, nothing special. This answer just presents another choice.

Comment: As said, it is always nice seeing innovative approaches. Although useful innovations. GetValue and SetValue (and not just this) are very high consuming (you can do performance tests if you don't believe me). Regarding my suggestion, sure it has been around a while, this is not something bad, right the contrary: that means that it delivers a right performance. For a simple and very common problem, using a simple and very common solution tends to best thing to do. But, of course, I am completely open to different approaches proven to be better (what, as said, don't think that is the case here)

Comment: BTW, the code I used is executed only once in the static constructor. That code will be the highest load when using `Reflection` but it is just done once, that would be a good improvement.

Comment: PS: not sure what has exactly to do databindings with the fact that using reflection is a time-consuming option.

Comment: OK... I will test your code (I just over-looked it and assumed that a custom class affecting the given method would be called every time the method is used).

Comment: Very nice approach, no doubt on that. But you are calling once GetValue and twice SetValue every time the ValueChanged event is triggered; performance is certainly an issue there. I insist: innovation is marvellous, but cannot lose its essence (a way to improve). I don't think that you should give more importance to the innovation itself and stop worrying about the associated improvement. Again, nice implementation but I cannot +1 it because don't think that is the best approach in this context.

Comment: @varocarbas it's up to you, however I updated it to use lesser code, in fact I tried with `currentValue` field before but it threw some exception, now after trying again, it works OK. the `currentValue` is the private field, by accessing it directly we will bypass the `OnValueChanged` and the event won't be fired. Anyway the most disadvantage of this approach is the **change of field name** in future implementations will break the application. That can happen although it's hardly.

Comment: I tested your previous version and worked fine. Reducing the number of expensive Reflection calls makes it better. You might even improve the GetValue/SetValue performance further. But the problem remains: why over-complicating something which might easily be solved? And, on top of that, affecting the resulting performance? I don't think that your approach should be considered at the same level than the other answers (as a solution for this problem). In any case, I insist in the fact that I am really happy to see innovative (and constant-improving) attitudes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could, when changing the value programmatically set a flag & then set it back afterwards, then you can check the flag in Value Changed event and ignore the event when you are setting the values programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to tell if the given variation was provoked by the user or by the code. What I usually do in these situations is relying on a global flag. Sample code:

```
bool autoChanged;
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!autoChanged)
    {
        //Perform actions you wish when the value is changed by the user
    }
    autoChanged = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    autoChanged = true; //Setting the flag to true every time the .Value property is modified via code
    numericUpDown1.Value = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Inherit NumericUpDown Class
2. Create a flag for determine value changed programmatically, or changed by GUI
3. Overload Value Property to set above flag

Here is my implementation in VB .NET.
Also work in case of data binding

```
Private m_blnIsValueChangedByGui As Boolean = True

Public Property IsValueChangedByGui() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_blnIsValueChangedByGui
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        m_blnIsValueChangedByGui = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Shadows Property Value() As Decimal
    Get
        Return MyBase.Value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        IsValueChangedByGui = False

        If (value > Me.Maximum) Then
            MyBase.Value = Me.Maximum
        ElseIf (value < Me.Minimum) Then
            MyBase.Value = Me.Minimum
        Else
            MyBase.Value = value
        End If

        IsValueChangedByGui = True
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Validated** event handler that triggers only when the user changes the value from the interface. This event triggers after the **ValueChanged** and will not be triggered when you change the value programmatically.